# Entity Framework 5 Release Candidate: Not handling nullable fields correctly

Tags: frameworks, entity, entity-framework-5

Entity Framework 5RC with ASP.NET MVC 4

I have a table with the following field in it:

Editor nvarchar(200) nullable

I generated a new EF model in my application and generated POCO entities using "Add Code Generation Item..." on the model's diagram.  I saved the changes, I cleaned my solution, and I rebuilt the entire solution.  When I run my application and try to add or edit this kind of entity, EF5RC reports that

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Editor', table '@T'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

The database table field is nullable.  I returned to the model and examined this field in the entity.  Its "Nullable" is set to "(None)", which is odd.  I would have expected it to be True.  I set it to True, saved the model's changed, cleaned the solution, and rebuilt the entire solution.  When I ran the application, I receive the same error.  The only way that I can seem to get around this issue is to set this field to some junk value in my MVC Controller.

In my ViewModel, this field is not being passed to the Create or Edit actions.

In my EF project, this field is annotated as follows...  Note tha it is not set as Required.

---

```
[Display(Name = "Title_Editor", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
[StringLength(200, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_200CharactersOrLess", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
public string Editor { get; set; }
```

---

I've tried to delete my entity from the model, clean the solution, recreate the entity and POCO class, but this issue persists.

This looks like an EF5RC bug to me...  Has anyone else encountered it?  How do I report it to the EF Development Team?

Thanks,

Mike

***************** EXCEPTION MESSAGE ************************

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was caught   Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at ExpirationTrax.Domain.Repositories.EFCustomerRepository.Update(BaseCustomer customer) in C:\PROJECTS\ExpirationTraxMVC\ExpirationTrax.Domain\Repositories\EFCustomerRepository.cs:line 49   InnerException: System.Data.UpdateException
       Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=System.Data.Entity
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            Message=Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Editor', table '@T'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.
            Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
            ErrorCode=-2146232060
            Class=16
            LineNumber=42
            Number=515
            Procedure=CustomersHistoryTrigger
            Server=DevPC\SqlExpress
            State=2
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
                 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you sure that your application is hitting correct database? This error comes from database, not from entity framework.

Comment: Yes, because when I assign a dummy value for Editor in my Controller for Add and Edit actions, they are successful.  This is why I think that there is a bug...

Comment: Here is what I have in my Create action in the CustomerController:

                baseCustomer.Editor = "blah";
                Repository.Add(baseCustomer);
                Repository.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: Here is the Repository.Add() method:
public void Add(BaseCustomer customer)
 {
    context.BaseCustomers.Add(customer);
 }

Comment: Here is the Repository.SubmitChanges() method:
public int SaveChanges()
{
    return context.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: Don't write code to comments. You can edit your question. Assigning dummy value does not make it bug. It just means that you have passed database requirement for not-null value. You must find why **database** is firing this exception.